# Using DNS to Redirect Several Domains into One Single Content. Disaster?

Tags: seo

When I searching our web site on Google I found three sites with the same content show up. I always thought we were using only one site www.foo.com, but it turn out we have www.foo.net and www.foo.info with the same content as www.foo.com.

I know it is extremely bad to have the same content under different URL. And it seems we have being using three domains for years and I have not seen punitive blunt so far.

What is going on? Is Google using new policy like this blog advocate?http://www.seodenver.com/duplicate-content-over-multiple-domains-seo-issues/

Or is it OK using DNS redirect? What should I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are managing the websites via Google Webmaster Tools, it is possible to specify the "primary domain".

However, the world of search engines doesn't stop with Google, so your best bet is to send a 301 redirect to your primary domain. For example.

```
www.foo.net should 301 redirect to www.foo.com

www.foo.net/bar should 301 redirect to www.foo.com/bar
```

and so on.

This will ensure that www.foo.com gets the entire score, rather than (potentially) a third of the score that you might get for link-backs (internal and external).

Answer (score 0):

Look into canonical links, as [documented](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) by Google.

> If your site has identical or vastly
>   similar content that's accessible
>   through multiple URLs, this format
>   provides you with more control over
>   the URL returned in search results. It
>   also helps to make sure that
>   properties such as link popularity are
>   consolidated to your preferred
>   version.

They explicitly state it will work [cross-domain](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/12/handling-legitimate-cross-domain.html).